# Using GeoIP Location in Display logic Qualtrics

Tags: geolocation, qualtrics

I have a question regarding appropriate use of the GeoIP Location in Qualtrics as part of display logic.

I wish to restrict the display of one question only to participants from London, England. I have looked at the [support page](https://www.qualtrics.com/support/survey-platform/survey-module/using-logic/#PossibleFieldsGeoIPLocation) regarding this topic. However, there is no further help about what values are accepted in specific fields available in GeoIP location. I have simply typed in "London" (see image below); however, they could also require coordinates or other values.

- Could you please advise how to set up the display logic with GeoIP Location only to London, England?
- Is it possible to restrict the GeoIP even further only to certain London Burrough for example? Can you please provide an example?
- Is it possible to restrict the GeoIP location to a polygon coordinates? For example, I will set up the polygon using [map polygon tool](https://www.keene.edu/campus/maps/tool/). Is it possible then restrict the display logic only to GeoIPs only within the polygon? Can you please provide an example?

[image: Display Logic with GeoIP Location]

Thank you for any help.